# what's different between esc_attr, htmlspecialchars and htmlentities

Tags: escaping

Can I simply use htmlspecialchars instead of esc_attr?

Comment: And you could also add `esc_html`

Answer (score 4):

esc_attr() is written specifically for escaping a string that is to be used as an html attribute, which means also escaping single and double-quote characters etc.

In general, it's better to use the [data validation API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Text_Nodes) that WP provides rather than the generic PHP functions.

Comment: And what is the difference between the WordPress function `esc_html` and the PHP function `htmlspecialchars` (with `ENT_QUOTES` flag)?
It is also good to note that using an official PHP function instead of a WordPress function has the advantage to have a more portable code, that you can use without CMS or with another CMS.

Comment: The WordPress function can be updated with other sanitization methods as we discover them.